# How to connect my website to online data base -server side settings-?

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

i'm developing a web site that connect to my hosted database and do some insertion and selection, but when i initiate the connection to the database it told me this:

> php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

so i checked out my connection code and i think it's correct:

```
    session_start();
define('DB_HOST', 's009.panelboxmanager.com');
define('DB_UID', 'cpanelUsernaem');
define('DB_PWD', 'Cpanelpassword');
define('DB_Name', 'geftqata_carrefour');

@ mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_UID, DB_PWD) or die(mysql_error());
```

So, do i have to do something in my CPanel ??
please help !

Comment: Plus i added % in remote mysql, i think this will allow any link to connect to the database

Comment: the hostname should probably be 'localhost' - your ISP will confirm. The login ID and password will **not** be your cPanel login and password - you have to create these for the database using a cPanel option,and `GRANT` access to the databse for the user you create.

Comment: @user2092317 if i didn't mention the host name, what i should mention else ?

Comment: @MikeW the problem is my site in a host different from the database host, and i create a for the database but i can't find a way to login with, the only way i can log in is the cpanel credential

Comment: Look FoR Phpmyadmin In Cpanel. Also, Don't Use Mysql_connect, Use Mysqli Or pdo

Comment: Probably the access from remote host to `s009.panelboxmanager.com` is blocked. Try to go to the CPanel at panelboxmanager.com, find the "Remote MySQL" under the database section, and add the hostname of your website. Not sure if it will work so I'm just putting it as a comment.